# How to write a method for json parsing url with NSURLConnection in NSObject class and get the NSDictionary from UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsoperation

How to write a method for parsing a json url with NSURLConnection in NSObject class and get the return value in UIViewController ? I know it can be done with operation block but don't know the exact method.

Currently I am doing the same thing with NSURLSession but I want this same code with NSURLConnection following is my current code.

```
-(void)jsonParseWithPostMethod:(void(^)(NSDictionary* result))handler andString:(NSString*) yourString andParam:(NSString *)param {


  NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
  NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

  NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:yourString];
  NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
  NSString * params =param;
  [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
  [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

  NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
                                                   completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                       NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
                                                       if(error == nil)
                                                       {
                                                           NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
                                                           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                               handler(json) ;

                                                           });

                                                       }

                                                   }];
  [dataTask resume];
}
```

and calling this method like that

```
[[Singelton getInstance] jsonParseWithPostMethod:^(NSDictionary* json){

} andString:urlString andParam:pramString];
```

Comment: Your question is too broad. Try to narrow it down - show us some code, etc

Comment: I just added some code plz check, same work needs to be done with nsurlconnection.